# Does excel consume more memory while storing data into single pages rather than the multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, optimization, memory, xlsxwriter

When I try to create a sheet, is it better to write the data into different sheets or into a single sheet?.

Is memory consumption increased while data is writing into different sheets instead of a single sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is memory consumption increased while data is writing into different sheets instead of a single sheet

If you are using XlsxWriter (like you added in the tags) then there is only a negligible memory footprint difference between those two methods.

Comment: yeah, when having so many sheets it memory consideration point. thq..